# Bing maps: Specified credentials invalid

Tags: bing, bing-api, bing-maps

I can't seem to get Bing to accept my API key from my dev server-- I've set up an API key from the bingmapsportal.com site, and set the URL to `http://localhost` and generated the key successfully.

I then implement the map as shown in the API docs, as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getMap(){
        var mapInitOpts = {
            credentials: 'mycredentials',
            mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road
        };
       var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapInitOpts);
     }
</script>
</head>
  <body onload="getMap();">
   <div id='map_canvas' style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%;"></div><br />
  </body>
</html>  

// map shows invalid credentials error
```

However, I always get the "Specified credentials invalid" message.

Any ideas on this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you had `'mycredentials'` act as a place holder for your actual credentials for this question posting, try using the API key from the interactive SDK:

```
AjtUzWJBHlI3Ma_Ke6Qv2fGRXEs0ua5hUQi54ECwfXTiWsitll4AkETZDihjcfeI
```

If the above works, and the key you obtained doesn't, then something is wrong with your key and you need to work with Bing Dev Support.

If the above key doesn't work, then there is something wrong with your development environment...